# Move data from one MySQL table to another

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to move data from one database (registrations) to another when the user clicks a button named delete. (I want to move the data to a table named archived)

Here is what i have tried (found from Google):

```
 $result=mysql_query("Insert Into archived (select * from registrations WHERE id=$id") ;
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This doesn't move it... can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have the same number of columns in both tables?

Comment: the tables are identical.

Comment: Are they in the same db?Also remove the parentheses.

Comment: There are in the same db, what is "the parentheses"?

Comment: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/parentheses.htm That thing you didn't close.

Comment: @Mihai Or "add" a parentheses ;-) See [peterm's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19620054/1415724)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does that query throw any error on executing it?

Comment: Note: Your query could get SQL Injection attack cause of your $id, never put variables in your queries.

more information https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly you're missing one parenthesis, which you don't have to use in this case at all

Change your query string to

```sql
Insert Into archived (select * from registrations WHERE id=$id)
                     ^                                        ^
```

or to just

```sql
Insert Into archived select * from registrations WHERE id=$id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3254e/1)** demo

Secondly `INSERT` doesn't return a resultset so you shouldn't use `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Thirdly if your intent was to **move** not just to copy data then you also need to delete the row that you copied afterwards.

---

Now you can put it all in a stored procedure

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE move_to_archive(IN _id INT)
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO archived 
    SELECT * 
      FROM registrations 
     WHERE id = _id;
    DELETE
      FROM registrations 
     WHERE id = _id;
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```sql
CALL move_to_archive(2);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f6c1/1)** demo

Comment: @peterm Shouldn't that be `WHERE id='$id' "` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No it shouldn't. `_id` is a procedure parameter. `$id` might be used in `$result = mysql_query("CALL move_to_archive($id)");`, but a parameterized query with `mysqli` is preferred.

Comment: @peterm I understand, however I've seen it so many times that people did not wrap variables in quotes and did not work.

Comment: @peterm I wasn't referring to `WHERE id = _id;` I was referring to `Insert Into archived select * from registrations WHERE id=$id`

Comment: using TRANSACTION please! plus one for that

Answer (score 1):

The query you are attempting just copies the information from one table to the other. You then have to delete it from the first table:

```
INSERT INTO archived 
SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE id = $id;

DELETE FROM registrations WHERE id = $id;
```

Comment: I have run this code, it has removed it from the registrations table but not moved it to the archived one?

Comment: @user2418857 You probably need to wrap your `$id` in quotes like this `SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE id = '$id';` and the same for the `DELETE`