# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM `teachers` WHERE user_id=' ' at line 1

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 $sql = " INSERT INTO `teachers_archive` 
 SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE user_id='$userid' ; 
 DELETE FROM `teachers` WHERE user_id='$userid' ";
```

I get this error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM `teachers` WHERE user_id=' '
>   at line 1

Where and what is the problem in the query? I can hardly understand! Please help to make it correct.

Comment: first you don't need to encapsulate $userid between quote. And second you should check your $userid value as it seems to be empty.

Comment: this is ur whole single query or 3 different ones?

Comment: Yap..this my single query. Here i am moving data to another table and after that delete. The referece i got from:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619933/move-data-from-one-mysql-table-to-another

Comment: Thanks for response. I just solved my problem by using loop.

Comment: Congrats on solving your problem. I'd advise adding your solution as an answer to the question. You can answer your own questions after some time has passed.

Comment: You might want to consider wrapping that up into a transaction

Comment: James Jones.. thanks.And i've added my solve bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is my solve:**

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['move'])) {

            $userid = $_POST["user_id"];
            $sql = " INSERT INTO `teachers_archive` SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE user_id='$userid'";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                $query = "DELETE FROM `teachers` WHERE user_id='$userid' ";
                if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
                    $message = "Success!";
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
                    echo"<script>document.location='mt.php';</script>";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }
        ?>
```