# Move data from one table with button to another table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have found this:

[Move data from one MySQL table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619933/move-data-from-one-mysql-table-to-another)

But in Laravel it's a bit different. Like him I want a button which deletes a row in a table like this one:
(Updated picture)
[image: Updated the picture]

Just to have an example. After he hit the button it should move the shown row into the database just like it is shown here and delete it afterwards. I really don't know how to start something like this in Laravel and I really can't find something related.

Maybe this will make it more clear:

```
$user_input = $request->userInput
$scores = DB::table('cd')
->join('customers', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer .lend_id')
->select('cd.fk_lend_id','cd.serialnumber','users.name', 'cd.created_at as lend on')
->where('cd.fk_lend_id',$request->$user_input)
->get();
```

Comment: *After he hit the button it should move the shown row into the database just like it is shown here and delete it afterwards.*. So is your question about how to delete data, how to move it or how to move it to a backup and then delete the original? Your question is quite vague, could you specify it more? For example, what have you tried already? Where did it fail?

Comment: My Question is how to move the data to another table and then delete the original data wich is shown as a picture.

Comment: Do you mean moving between database tables or between HTML tables? And secondly, what have you tried?

Comment: @Devi in the picture you show one row of a HTML table, so it's not really clear ;)

Comment: I have edited my post now you can see the inner join wich is the core of the shown table....

Comment: I have uploaded a new picture to make it more clearly what i want to do

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have two tables: `firsts` and `seconds`
For Laravel you must have two Models for these two tables: `First` and `Second` respectively.

Now, in your controller,

```
//import your models
use App\First;
use App\Second;

//create a function which takes the id of the first table as a parameter
public function test($id)
{
    $first = First::where('id', $id)->first(); //this will select the row with the given id

    //now save the data in the variables;
    $sn = $first->serialnumber;
    $cust = $first->customer;
    $lendon = $first->lend_on;
    $first->delete();

    $second = new Second();
    $second->serialnumber = $sn;
    $second->customer = $cust;
    $second->lend_on = $lendon;
    $second->save();

    //then return to your view or whatever you want to do
    return view('someview);

}
```

Remember the above controller function is called on button clicked and an `id`  must be passed.

The route will be something like this:

```
Route::get('/{id}', [
    'as' => 'test',
    'uses' => 'YourController@test',
]);
```

And, your button link like:

`<a href="{{ route('test',$id) }}">Button</a>`

Comment: My table which is shown above is just an inner join. So i have the table lend which is joining the table customers. And the result is the picture above. Is it still possible with the code you shared here? If you want i can show you the inner join.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simpler way to do the Laravel "move record" part of this.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\TableOne;
use App\Models\TableTwo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MoveOneRecord extends Controller
{

    public static function move_one_record(Request $request)
    {

        // before code

        // get id
        $id = intval( $request->input('id', 0) );

        // grab the first row of data
        $row_object = TableOne::where('id', $id))->first();

        // check if we have data
        if (empty($row_object)) { throw new Exception("No valid row data."); }

        // convert to array
        $row_array = $row_object->toArray();

        // unset the row id (assuming id autoincrements)
        unset($row_array['id']);

        // insert the row data into the new table (assuming all fields are the same)
        TableTwo::insert($row_array);

        // after code

    }

}
```