# Laravel how to move data from table to another

Tags: laravel-5

Is there any simple way to move data from table to table using the id? I want to get all the info inside the first table using the id, insert it to another table, and then delete it from current one using Laravel.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502989/move-data-from-one-table-with-button-to-another-table-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both tables have the same schema you can do:
`TableB::create(TableA::find($id));`

Comment: I found another way by adding active = 0 and 1 in database when its 1 show when its 0 don't show but now i need to update the value in database from blade.php file any help?

Comment: Update the value from the controller. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates